# pass data from service to the component - Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I am trying to post data to an api and return data to the service that called the api. This service will return the data to the component that called the service.

I am getting the data in the component but i couldn't figure out how to access the data in order to display them in the html. I am getting the data in this format:

[image]

this is my service
    public getPaymentDetails(loan,payment){
               console.log("reached payment details");

```
           let queryParameters = new URLSearchParams();
           let headerParams = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
           let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: headerParams,
                search: queryParameters
            };


            const url = this.basePath + '/api/v1/collection/payment';


            // let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            this.http.post(url, {loan,payment} , requestOptions)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    // console.log(data);
                    this.return_data.push(data.json());
                },
                data => {
                    // console.log(data);
                });
                return this.return_data;

       }
```

this is my component that calls the service:

```
getPaymentDetails(): void {
      //will need a separate api
      console.log("hi get payment details")

      this.payment_data = this.collectionService.getPaymentDetails(this.loan,this.amountForm.value["payment"]);

      console.log(this.payment_data)
      // for(var i=0;i<=payment_data.length;i++){

      // }

  }
```

When console logging the payment_data[0] i get the value undefined

Answer (score 0):

It is occurring for asynchronous behavior. It calls the function and then print the console. The functions executions is not finished yet. You have to wait until the data returns.

In your service

```
    let queryParameters = new URLSearchParams();
    let headerParams = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headerParams,
        search: queryParameters
    };

    const url = this.basePath + '/api/v1/collection/payment';

    // let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.post(url, { loan, payment }, requestOptions);
```

In Your Component

```
getPaymentDetails(): void {
      //will need a separate api
      console.log("hi get payment details")

      this.payment_data = this.collectionService.getPaymentDetails(this.loan,this.amountForm.value["payment"]).subscribe(// do your logic here);
  }
```

You can use a Table to show the data.

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "test-component",
    styles: [],
    template: `<div clss="row">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>CBC_DUE</th>
                        <th>CURRENT_MONTH_INSTLAMENT</th>
                        <th>LPP</th>
                        <th>TOTAL_DUE</th>

                    </tr>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of payment_data; let i=index">
                        <td>{{item?.CBC_DUE}}</td>
                        <td>{{item?.CURRENT_MONTH_INSTLAMENT}}</td>
                        <td>{{item?.LPP}}</td>
                        <td>{{item?.TOTAL_DUE}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>`,

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Observer` here to listen service finish event. So your data can be taken from service:

```
this.collectionService.getPaymentDetails(...).subscribe(data => this.payment_data = data);
```

Your service might looks like:

```
public getPaymentDetails(loan,payment) {
   return new Observable(observer => {
      ...

      this.http.post(url, {loan,payment} , requestOptions).subscribe(data => {
         ...
         return observer.next(data);
      });
   });
}
```